# Check if a browser supports a specific MIME type?

Tags: php, browser, mime

How can i check if the browser supports a specific mime type with php?

Answer (score 1):

You could analyze the [*Accept* header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) to see if the type or a superset of that type is listed.

But notice that *Accept* is a list of rated values and a [quality value](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.9) of 0 means not accepted. And browsers send different *Accept* values based on their expectations for that resource (e.g. a resource referenced in `IMG` element is expected to be an element of `image/*`).

Comment: Alternatively, if it's about inline-displayed media, nesting `<object>` elements offloads that decision to the browser.

Comment: so could i use this to check for flash player?

Comment: @tarnfeld: I think you should better use the way Johannes Rössel described.