# Detect if Windows 10 UAP app installed from web page

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

A web page in any web browser can invoke Windows 10 UAP via a protocol link.

Is there way to detect in the web page itself in a web browser if specific Windows 10 app is already installed?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, you can't do that using javascript. 
That wouldn't be anything good for security.

However, you can check if MIME type is supported, but it has to be installed in a browser.

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34044915/3000331

Comment: Thank you. What does "has to be installed in a browser" mean? MIME type is a registry entry.

Comment: It has to be integrated in a browser or as an extension. For example, you can check whether PDF is supported, it will report you if browser is capable of opening PDF or not. The same is for java and so on.

Comment: So can this MIME type detection be done in any browser as is or it requires special plug-in?

Comment: It can be done in every browser, but it's limited to MIME types supported by browser, not the system. You can't detect system apps installed, but you can detect Java Plugin and so on.