# Is it possible to check if a mime type is supported by browser to display?

Tags: javascript, browser, mime-types

I want to display a "open in new tab" button on my blob files *if* the mime type of this file is supported by the browser (Chrome/Firefox/Edge). Currently I only checking if the mime type of the file response is `application/pdf` or `image/png` and from there I know I can display it in a new tab.

But is there an easy way to check if the mime type is supported so I don't need checks for every image/text format?

I have found [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704489/javascript-get-mime-type-support?noredirect=1&lq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835401/check-browser-support-for-specific-mime-type?rq=3) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171809/check-if-a-browser-supports-a-specific-mime-type) with the same problem but they are all way to outdated and doesn't work anymore. `navigator.mimeTypes` or `navigator.plugins` only show me pdf plugins.

Comment: Why not show only safe file types?

Comment: What exactly are safe file types? The use case is that a user can upload every type he wants but only at browser supported files the "show" button will be displayed.

Comment: Ones that you know all browsers can support

Comment: yeah thats the alternative. But I just thought that maybe there is a better way to get for example an array of supported mime types from the browser and check with those. Thats why I am asking here so I don't need to write `if (file.mimeType === 'application/pdf')` ten+ times.

Comment: That’s probably not supported as it could lead to fingerprinting

Comment: @sirzento have you tried using `screnshotSupport` method of the `HTMLCanvasElement` object. or  `checkMimeType` method of the `XMLHttpRequest` object.